# How can I build this Observable?

Tags: rx-java

I need help building this Observable. I want:

1. Get `Observable<FilmInfo>` from an `User`'s id
2. From that `FilmInfo`'s id, retrieve a `Film`
3. Once completed, return an `Observable<UserFilm>` that contains both `FilmInfo` and `Film`

I have this:

```
@Override
public Observable<UserFilm> filmsForUser(final User user) {
    return infoStore.filmsInfoForUser(user.id())
            .flatMap(new Func1<FilmInfo, Observable<Film>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Film> call(final FilmInfo info) {
                    return filmsStore.get(info.id());
                }
            }).map(new Func1<Film, UserFilm>() {
                @Override
                public UserFilm call(Film film) {
                    //I need "info" here!
                }
            });
}
```

Here, I have an `Observable<Film>`, but I need to map it to an `Observable<UserFilm>`. Problem is that I can't use the `info` variable to build the `UserFilm`. I have tried with `combineLatest` but I don't know how to use it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the 2-argument overload of `flatMap`:

```
@Override
public Observable<UserFilm> filmsForUser(final User user) {
    return infoStore
        .filmsInfoForUser(user.id())
        .flatMap(filmInfo -> filmsStore.get(info.id()), (filmInfo, film) -> {
             // use filmInfo, film here!
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
@Override
public Observable<UserFilm> filmsForUser(final User user) {
    return infoStore.filmsInfoForUser(user.id()).flatMap(new Func1<FilmInfo, Observable<UserFilm>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<UserFilm> call(FilmInfo info) {
            return Observable.combineLatest(Observable.just(info), filmsStore.get(info.id()),
                    new Func2<FilmInfo, Film, UserFilm>() {
                        @Override
                        public UserFilm call(FilmInfo filmInfo, Film film) {
                            //I have all I need here!
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}
```